# Alt+Ctrl behavior different from Ctrl+Alt?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, workspaces

Specifically I am trying to use the workspace switching shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>. They work fine when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then an <kbd>Arrow</kbd> key, but not when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>. This behavior even carries over for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> commands for moving windows between workspaces. I am certain this behavior was not always so. How can I get back to the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd> order invariance?

Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit.

EDIT: Turns out this only happens when the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> key is on. I have no reason to ever have <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> off, so I would really like to understand why <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> is somehow changing my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> behavior.

EDIT 2: This only happens with the left alt key.

Comment: While I can't answer your question, I can give some potential answerer's some food for thought. This a very odd behavior. Ctrl and Alt are modifier keys, so it shouldn't matter what order they're pressed in as long as they are both depressed when hitting an arrow key. Sounds like this might be an xkbd issue?

Comment: Do you have another keyboard (different brand/type) to confirm this is a software issue?

Comment: I tried using the OnBoard virtual keyboard and it worked properly, however it only has one ctrl and one alt key, so I'm not sure it's a good test of an issue that specifically occurs with left-alt. I don't have easy access to another keyboard I can test with.

Comment: @gertvdijk it's definitely not a hardware problem. I can go into a guest session and everything works fine. I just need to figure out what I need to reset. I'm not particularly attached to any configuration settings I have right now, so if I can just rm -rf something somewhere I'd be happy.

Comment: @Githlar, if this is an xkbd issue, how might I go about confirming/addressing it?

Comment: @gertvdijk I've tested with a different keyboard. Definitely not a hardware problem.

Comment: I have the same problem in 14.04 with LCtrl and LSuper in combination with number key. Num Lock does not solve it.

Comment: Dumb question: do you have a full-sized AT-style keyboard or is this on a keyboard/laptop without a separate numeric keyboard?