# Super+digit takes precedence over Ctrl+Super+digit

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, workspaces

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>0-9</kbd> to switch workspace.

I also use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>0-9</kbd> to start programs that are pinned to the bar (unity default).

The problem is that when I try to switch workspace, if I happen to press <kbd>Super</kbd> before <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>0-9</kbd> is executed as if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> was never pressed although it is.

How do I make sure that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>0-9</kbd> is recognized as such, whatever the order in which <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> were pressed?

Comment: Another user had the problem with left Ctrl and Alt in 12.10, this seems to be fixed in 14.04. The issue must be something similar for RSuper and RCtrl. http://askubuntu.com/questions/299361/altctrl-behavior-different-from-ctrlalt?rq=1 . It looked like Num Lock would help first, but it does not in my case.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version, because this doesn't happen in 14.04?

Comment: @Radu 14.04, the keys are Super_R and Control_R. Ctrl+Super+digit are not default I believe, where did you map them to test?

Comment: On my Kubuntu 14.06 x64 with KDE don't have this problem: for example, `ctrl`+`super`+`7` and another order `super`+`ctrl`+`7` run the same action although `super`+`7` runs the different command.

Comment: Interesting. Is it `Super_R` and `Control_R`?

Comment: @Ruslan: on the other hand it's not very surprising, I suspect the problem is related to Unity or Compiz.